# Any legitimate way to get the JMF source code

Tags: java, licensing, jmf

According to [link](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/reference/faqs/index.html#jmfsource) here , it is possible to get the source code under Sun Community Source Licensing (SCSL); however, I can not find any place to pursuit this and [this](http://wwws.sun.com/software/communitysource/jmf/) link is obsolete now.
Any information?

NOTE: To be specific, i need only source code of JMF 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that only way is to contact a Oracle sales.

Answer (score 4):

After a bit of Googling I found a site that seems to have it archived at http://ohmydear.tistory.com/31. Look for the link to a ZIP file near the bottom of the page. From the file name it looks like it's the JMF 2.1.1e sources.